# Cant move the cursor using a brand new mouse on a brand new computer but the clicks work

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I recently bought the mouse Dragonwar Thor and plugged it into my new Surface pro. The cursor does not move on moving the mouse but the right and left click of the mouse work.

I had an older mouse of the same model that I used to use with my older Surface pro and it used to work until it suddenly stopped. Could it be that some Windows update just broke the support for this mouse? Is there any way I can figure this out for sure?

Comment: Did you change mouse surfaces? Certain surfaces will not work with optical/laser mice. It's also possible the mouse speed has been adjusted to near zero. Do other mice work?

Comment: The surface has been the same so thats not an issue. And other mice also do work.

Answer (score 0):

A mouse is a simple device that should work correctly out of the box.
The Dragonwar Thor mouse is advertised as suitable for almost every surface,
so doesn't require special conditions.

If it has a problem where other mouses of similar type work fine,
this looks like a bad mouse.
Return it to the store and ask for a replacement.